# How to test whether birds spend more time in specific areas along a time-segmented track?

Tags: time-series, spatial, ecology

I have geolocation data on birds with 1 position per day (latitude + longitude) plus I have for each day, a corresponding binary time series that takes values 0 or 1.

There is periods of minimum 10 days during which days are zeros followed by period during which days are ones and so forth.

ex:

```
> data[1:11, ]

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
> data[12:26, ] 

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
>data[26:39, ]  

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

. . .
```

I would like to statistically assess whether the bird is staying more in the same areas in the "1" periods relative to the "0" period.

The `adehabitatLT` package offers ways to segment an animal track in a specified number of segment based on speed for example. But this is not what I want. I want to see if during 1 versus 0, the bird is staying more, or not, in the same area.

Answer (score 0):

1. Calculate the Euclidean distance (or use some spherical projection) from latitude and longitude between adjacent days. Carefully describe why you may actually "move quite quickly but stay where you are on adjacent days" as a limitation.
2. Create run-length event encodings for each sequence of 0s and 1s.
3. Aggregate the total distance traveled over the number of days for each period and summarize the mean distance traveled per day.
4. Use a t-test to test for a difference in means between mean-distance-traveled-per-day in the 0 group vs the 1 group.

Comment: I clarified the question, both in my mind and on the post. I think your approach could be a good idea when working with speed, altough t-test suppose normality, and I'm not sure whether distances  follow a gaussian as it can not be negative. and the distribution is rarely symmetrical.

Comment: distance measure that you suggest essentially loses one dimension of the spatial information. it makes two dimensional movements treated like one dimensional.

Comment: @Aksakal I don't see how that's a bad thing. As far as I gather, if a bird flies a circle of circumference 1 meter every second, then its velocity is 1 m/s.

Comment: @AdamO your bird will fly the distance $L$ vs. $\sqrt L$ if you were measuring the area

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the coordinates into Cartesian coordinate system, then calculate the two dimensional dispersion. The dispersion would be my measure of localization, and I could compare it between 0 and 1 sequences.

The two dimensional dispersion is the square root of the product of eigenvalues of the covariance matrix.

You can get fancy and first fit the kernel distribution into the coordinates, then get the covariance matrix using the fitted distribution. If you have a lot of data, this can be more stable (big maybe) in presence of outliers. As with any linear variance based measure, this measure will be sensitive to outliers.

If the birds fly far away within each sequence of 0 and 1 then we have a problem with a curvature of earth. My approach is based on a flat surface. I think it's a good approximation when the distances are small within in each sequence. In this case within each sequence we assume a flat surface, locally flat so to speak.

If the distances are large, then we'll have to come up with an analog of variance. One such option is geographic standard deviation relative to the geographic mean as described in [this write up](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/geographic-statistics-for-point-locations-on-a-sphere.html) in MATLAB. They first find the geographic mean, then calculate the square distances from the mean and average. Again, as any distance measure this will suffer from outlier sensitivity, so you may want to apply some robust form of the variance on top.

Comment: If I convert into Descartes system, if I end up with high dispersion it could be the result of the earth geometry as longitudes are more spaced near equator than at the poles, and not reflect actual wider areas.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to compute the residence time using R (package `adehabitatLT`). The residence time is the time spent in a circle of a specified radius traced around each successive position of the bird. It is then possible to extract this data for each relocation and use it in statistical models.
It is also possible to extract the number of revisit using the `recurse` package.